# Its not returning even though i have a cout

Tags: c++, debugging

It doesn't seem to be returning anything for some reason can anybody point me to the right direction
here is my code
The count leaves function

```
template<class T>
int BinaryTree<T>::leaves(TreeNode* n)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (n->left == NULL && n->right == NULL)
        count++;
    else
    {
        if (n->left != NULL)
        count += leaves(n->left);
        if (n->right != NULL)
        count += leaves(n->right);
    }

    return count;

}
```

The getter for that function

```
template<class T>
int BinaryTree<T>::numLeaves()
{
    return leaves(root);
}
```

and the main

```
case 6:
                cout << "The total number of leaves are " << tree.numLeaves() << endl;
                break;
```

for some reason everything seems to be working as it doesnt crash the code but it does not return anything so for example if I input 5 4 2 9 0 it should return 2 with "2" and "9" being the leaves, but it doesn't can someone explain to me on what's wrong

Comment: And yes I did a add all the nessary #includes

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mcve]. I also recommend that you learn how to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement.

Comment: I'd _guess_ that it's not reaching `case 6` … But that's a complete guess based on too little information.

Comment: @ChrisMM that's not it but would you like me to show you my main?

Comment: We need a minimal reproducible example. Enough code to reproduce the issue, but cutting out all the extra information we don't need.

Comment: I did do that though @chrissMM you have all the information you need and  let me know if you need more info

Comment: @ThanosCheeks what you provided is NOT a [mcve]. We can't copy/paste it into a compiler and run it as-is to reproduce the problem. For instance, how does `tree` get populated in the first place?

Comment: scratch that im so sorry

Comment: i just solved it how do i delete my quesion

Comment: Remy Lebau please i used an insert function i created but that isn't where the error is and anyway i solved it